# Maclaurin Expansion of $\ln(3+x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm currently evaluating a simple Maclaurin expansion, the confusion I have with is why the expansion of this function is constructed to be:

$\ln\left[3\left(1+\dfrac{x}{3}\right)\right]$ as opposed to $\ln[1+(2+x)]$, I know that we get different results for both, but why is the previous correct, and the latter incorrect?

$\ln(3)+\ln(1+\dfrac{x}{3}) = \ln(3) + \dfrac{x}{3} - \dfrac{x^2}{18} + \ldots$

$\ln(1+(2+x)) = (2+x) - \dfrac{(2+x)^2}{2} + \ldots = -x -\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\ldots$

My understanding so far is that, if we use $1+x$ that would change the point we are estimating about, which is suppose to be $x=0$, which would change it to a Taylor series. However, I still think I'm missing something more fundamental in my explanation.

Comment: You have to specify which point to expand around. Also note that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ (meaning expanding around $1$) is $1$.

Comment: i'm expanding about the point x = 0, since it is Maclaurin Series

Comment: Perhaps you could include the two "different results" that you get, to make it easier for us to explain the differences between them.

Comment: I included the two different results.

Comment: How did you get $-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\cdots$?

Comment: The first expansion is done around $x=0$ while the second  is done around $x=-2$

Comment: ok thanks claude, i just wanted to clarify, it was what I initially thought, but i felt it was wrong.